# Why does YouTube interfere with iPad hover drop-down menus?

Tags: ios, css, drop-down-menu, youtube

I've encountered an odd behaviour of simple CSS hover based drop-down menus on the iPad (iOS 7).

The menus work as expected, first tap shows the drop-down and the second goes to the link unless there is a YouTube video on the page.  If there is a YouTube video on the page the first tap shows the menu for a short time and then goes to the link without a second tap.

The HTML is:

```
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="/menutest/index.html">Menu Test Home</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/menutest/youtube.html">Youtube Video Page</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/menutest/plain.html">Plain Text Page</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

The CSS is:

```
nav ul li ul {
    display:none;
}

nav ul li:hover ul {
    display:block;
}
```

The YouTube code is:

```
<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/O8_eFRZP1uQ?showinfo=0&rel=0" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

This problem does not occur with videos hosted on Vimeo or Wistia.

I posted an earlier question on this topic but withdrew it as I had not isolated the problem and did not ask a clear question.

An example can be found at http://silvermapleweb.com/menutest/

Comment: Does anyone found any solution for this?

Comment: For an unknown reason, if you add about 60px margin on top of your link, it works correctly. I further isolated this problem and posted the question in a more specific way here, I hope this is alright to do on Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25167504/ios-hover-then-touch-behavior-impacted-by-youtube-video-in-frame-on-page

Answer (score 2):

When the user is at /index.html, and you click the Menu Test Home, the page is already on that page, so probably ios safari does not reload the page, and therefore the dropdown is showed correctly.

When on the youtube page (/youtube.html), and pressing the Menu Test Home link, the user is actually sent to a new page. The menu is showed briefly before the page is reloaded with new content (now at /index.html).

If you don't want to send the user to a new page, don't use a href location, or add a event.preventDefault(); on a click event on the Menu Test Home link.

Comment: Please explain why it works properly when the user is on the "plain text page".  That page is just like the "youtube" page without the "youtube"

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. Depending on hover for a touch device does not sound like a good idea in the first place.

Comment: I agree it's not a good idea, but a lot of sites use hover and most touch devices support some kind of emulation. I'm surprised that nobody knows what is going on with youtube vs iOS hover emulation.  I read recently that Apple is actually working on a touch screen that supports real hovering, i.e. you hover a cm above the screen with your finger and it triggers the HTML hover state.  I hope they fix this when that comes out.

Comment: Although this doesn't really answer the question you have provided more information than anyone else in the last 2 weeks that I've been researching this.  For that reason I'm awarding you the bounty, but not marking the answer as correct.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to specify **[z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)** for the drop down menu. Try this :

```
nav ul li:hover ul {
    display:block;
    z-index:1000;
}
```

Comment: adding the z-index makes no difference.  Note that the menu works properly if you replace the YouTube with Vimeo.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and was unable to find a pure CSS solution.  Using JavaScript to implement the drop down solved the problem for me.  Here's one way to do it in JavaScript (probably not the best, but it works):

```
jQuery('nav > ul > li').hover(function() {
var $parent = jQuery(this);
var $dropdown = $parent.children('ul');

$dropdown.show(0,function() {    
    $parent.mouseleave(function() {
        var $this = jQuery(this);
        $this.children('ul').fadeOut(10);
    });
});
});
```

You would then need to delete the display:block; in the CSS.

I did not test this code with your exact HTML, so forgive any typos!

Here's more details on my solution: http://brianshim.com/webtricks/drop-down-menus-on-ios-and-android/